# How to perform fast spatial queries in c#

Tags: c#, performance, indexing, openstreetmap, spatial

I need to create code that given a GPS location point (lat,lon) will find the top 3 closest points from a huge point collection ([OSM nodes](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node)).

The first option is to have the huge point collection stored in a database and create spatial indexes. Then use a query with built-in spatial methods to get the results. I consider this approach not to be the fastest since the whole querying proccess will require time consuming transactions between software and database. Correct me if I am wrong.

The second option is to have the entire point collection loaded in memory as the program starts. I believe this approach will have better performance. Obviously there is a need to create indexes to avoid iterating through the entire collection since doing so will make performance slower than using a database.

But I do not know how to create indexes in a c# data collection. Is there any .Net library or other approach that indexes in memory spatial data in order to perform fast queries on them?

**EDIT:** This question although similar to the one considered as duplicate it introduces the question whether database or in-memory approach has better performance.

Comment: https://www.leapinggorilla.com/Blog/Read/1005/spatial-search-in-lucenenet

Comment: For the in-memory representation of your data, you might want to take a look at [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

Comment: Yes this is a good idea and I am curently looking at it. I edited my question to distinguish it from the one considered duplicate.